# How to fix my regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I have been attempting to fix my regex but I cannot.I want capture group 3 to contain all letters and white space between the digit `3` and **capture group 2**.

```
.*([A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{3})+\s+([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}\w)\s{2}(.*?)\d
```

My regex properly gets this but it has no line breaks.

```
ACG 3141  Intermediate Financial Accounting II  3 hrs
```

My regex cant get

```
ACG 3501  Financial Accounting for Governmental and 
Nonprofit Organizations  
3 hrs 

TAX 4001  Taxation of Business Entities and 
Transactions  
3 hrs
```

I cant figure out how to use `(.*?)\d` to go to the next digit ignoring the line breaks in **capture group 3**.

Comment: I'd guess you need the `s` modifier so the `.` extends to new lines..(not a java'r so that might be wrong)

Comment: ...so `s` modifier didn't work? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL `In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators.`

Comment: Dotall modifier will do the job, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/72yGrr/1).

Comment: @chris85 I mean I am trying it in http://regexr.com/ but its not working.Thanks for responding!

Comment: Show your usage that isn't working..

Comment: Tip: you probably don't want to capture the stuff until the next digit, so use `(?:.*?)` instead of `(.*?)` to make it a non-capturing group.